Is "Chief Agent" an appropriate translation of ἀρχηγός at Heb 12:2?
At Hebrews 12:2 is "Chief Agent" an appropriate or preferred translation of Strongs G747 ἀρχηγός archēgos ar-khay-gos'. From G746 and G71; a chief leader: - author, captain, prince?
Hebrews 12:1-3 King James Version

1 Wherefore seeing we also are compassed about with so great a cloud of witnesses, let us lay aside every weight, and the sin which
doth so easily beset us, and let us run with patience the race that is
set before us, 2 `Looking unto Jesus the author and finisher of
our faith; who for the joy that was set before him endured the cross,
despising the shame, and is set down at the right hand of the throne
of God. 3 For consider him that endured such contradiction of
sinners against himself, lest ye be wearied and faint in your minds.


The Greek word ἀρχηγός (archégos) only occurs in a few places in the NT and always means "originator, author, founder, prince, leader" (Strongs).  It is composed of two words:

archó = beginning, start, chief
hégeomai = (verb) leader

Thus, the word ἀρχηγός (archégos) means the chief initiator.  Its use in the NT is best illustrated by its occurrences - the word is always only and applied only as a title of Jesus:

Acts 3:15 - You killed the Author/Originator of life [ie, Jesus], but God raised Him from the dead, and we are witnesses of the fact.
Acts 5:31 - God exalted Him to His right hand as Leader/Prince and Savior, in order to grant repentance and forgiveness of sins to Israel.
Heb 2:10 - In bringing many sons to glory, it was fitting for God, for whom and through whom all things exist, to make the Author/Originator of their salvation perfect through suffering.
Heb 12:2 - Let us fix our eyes on Jesus, the Author/Originator and perfecter of our faith, who for the joy set before Him endured the cross, scorning its shame, and sat down at the right hand of the throne of God.

Thus, "chief agent" is not a valid translation of this word.  Jesus is portrayed as the actual Author, Originator or eternal life and salvation, not merely an agent.  I also note the following:

Acts 4:12 - Salvation exists in no one else [ie, Jesus], for there is no other name under heaven given to men by which we must be saved.”
1 John 5:11, 12 - And this is that testimony: God has given us eternal life, and this life is in His Son. Whoever has the Son has life; whoever does not have the Son of God does not have life.
John 1:3, 4 - Through Him [the Word] all things were made, and without Him nothing was made that has been made. In Him was life, and that life was the light of men.
1 John 1:1, 2 - That which was from the beginning, which we have heard, which we have seen with our own eyes, which we have gazed upon and touched with our own hands—this is the Word of life. And this is the life that was revealed; we have seen it and testified to it, and we proclaim to you the eternal life that was with the Father and was revealed to us.
John 8:12 - Once again, Jesus spoke to the people and said, “I am the light of the world. Whoever follows Me will never walk in the darkness, but will have the light of life.”
John 10:28 - I give them eternal life, and they will never perish. No one can snatch them out of My hand.
John 11:25, 26 - Jesus said to her, “I am the resurrection and the life. Whoever believes in Me will live, even though he dies. And everyone who lives and believes in Me will never die. Do you believe this?”

